# What does the third parameter in the following mongoose query do?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', yourSchema);

// find each person with a last name matching 'Ghost', selecting the `name` and `occupation` fields
Person.findOne({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }, 'name occupation', function (err, person) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation) // Space Ghost is a talk show host.
})
```

The code is taken straight from their website.

My question is what would the Person schema look like? How you search for `name.last` in `occupation`?

My understanding of the Person schema is below:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      last: String
    }
    occupation: {

    }  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How you search for name.last in occupation?

The `person schema` seems to have 2 fields name and occupation. The name is further divided into `first` and `last`.The `occupation` field isn't having any further parts ,that's why `person.occupation` is returning a `string`. Had it been divided into further parts then `person.occupation` would have returned an `object`.

> What would the Person schema look like?

```
var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
  first: String,
  last: String
},
occupation: String  
});
```

Comment: But what is the point of having the third parameter 'name occupation'? Would the query not already work without this parameter?

Comment: Yup it would work, its just that all other fields except from name and occupation would also be retrieved. Its 2nd not 3rd parameter. 1st is               `{ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }`.